# Apple iPad/iPhone photos app - delete photo animation

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, photo

I am looking to create the animation like the one used in the photo app for iPad/iPhone for deleting a photo. The photo needs to move to the recycle bin.

Is this a standard animation? Or do we need lots of coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the animation they use for deleting photos is "Suck". ;p and possibly animating it to the Trash button's rect, while at the same time animating the Trash icon.